# How to map the results of Principal Component Analysis back to the actual features that were fed into the model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

When I run the code below, I see the '`pca.explained_variance_ratio_`' and a histogram, which shows the proportion of variance explained for each feature.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.stats import anova

mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars", "datasets", cache=True).data
df = pd.DataFrame(mtcars)

x = df.iloc[:,2:]

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pca = PCA(n_components=11)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(df)


# Plotting the variances for each PC
PC = range(1, pca.n_components_+1)
plt.bar(PC, pca.explained_variance_ratio_, color='gold')
plt.xlabel('Principal Components')
plt.ylabel('Variance %')
plt.xticks(PC)
```

[image]

How can I map PCA 1 and 2 back to the original features in the data frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each PCs is a linear combination of your variables. For example PC1 will be (where X1,X2 represents each dependent variable):

[image]

So w11, w22 would be your loadings and they would represent each features influence on the associated PC. Basically they would show the amount of correlation with your PCs See [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143905/loadings-vs-eigenvectors-in-pca-when-to-use-one-or-another) or maybe something like this [blog](https://scentellegher.github.io/machine-learning/2020/01/27/pca-loadings-sklearn.html) for an explanation with sklearn.

In your example, you did not scale your data before PC, so the vector with the most loading would be the one with the largest magnitude. So let's do this properly:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars", "datasets", cache=True).data
df = pd.DataFrame(mtcars)
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)
pca = PCA(n_components=11)
pca.fit(X)

# Plotting the variances for each PC
PC = range(1, pca.n_components_+1)
plt.bar(PC, pca.explained_variance_ratio_, color='gold')
plt.xlabel('Principal Components')
plt.ylabel('Variance %')
plt.xticks(PC)
```

[image]

These are the loadings:

```
PCnames = ['PC'+str(i+1) for i in range(pca.n_components_)]
Loadings = pd.DataFrame(pca.components_,columns=PCnames,index=df.columns)

Loadings.iloc[:,:2]

                PC1        PC2
    mpg      0.362531   -0.373916
    cyl      0.016124    0.043744
    disp    -0.225744   -0.175311
    hp      -0.022540   -0.002592
    drat     0.102845    0.058484
    wt      -0.108797    0.168554
    qsec     0.367724    0.057278
    vs       0.754091    0.230825
    am      -0.235702   -0.054035
    gear     0.139285   -0.846419
    carb     0.124896    0.140695
```

Roughly this means observations with high `vs` will have higher scores on the first component (PC1) and those will high `am` will have low scores likewise. And you can check their influence:

```
Loadings["PC1"].sort_values().plot.barh()
```

[image]

Comment: Ohhhh, that's awesome!! Thanks for sharing your thoughts on this!!!!

Comment: @StupidWolf. AWESOME! For a beginner trying to understand PCA this was an excellent insight. Thanks for sharing..

Answer (score 0):

Use the `inverse_transform` method:

```
x_fromPCA = pca.inverse_transform(principalComponents)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't tell me what is PCA1, PCA2, PCA3, etc. There must be some way to know what feature is PCA1, right.

Comment: @ASH there is not; it is the price you have to pay when using PCA (i.e. you loose interpretability).

Comment: Oh, I see. Ok, thanks for confirming. At least we have Feature Importance in the Random Forest algo.

Comment: The columns in X_fromPCA correspond to the columns in principalComponents. However, these columns are not the same as the feature columns in x, seeing that the principal components are projections of your original data in a different vector basis system.